# Continuous limit of a discrete stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that I divide the time interval $[0,T]$ into $n$ subintervals with end points $t_k = \frac{k}{n}T$ for $k=0,1,\cdots,n$ and I consider the following process $X^n_t = X^n_{t_k}$ if $t_k < t < t_{k+1}$ where
\begin{equation}
X_{t_{k+1}} = \begin{cases}
X^n_{t_k} + \delta X^n_{t_k}(1-X^n_{t_k}), &\qquad \text{with probability $\frac{1}{2}$}\\
X^n_{t_k} - \delta X^n_{t_k}(1-X^n_{t_k}), &\qquad \text{with probability $\frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for some constant $\delta > 0$ and an initial condition $X^n_0 \in [0,1]$. If I set $\delta = \sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}$ and send $n\rightarrow +\infty$, would the process $\{X^n_t\}$ converges (in distribution, or any sense) to the continuous time process
\begin{equation}
X_T = X_0 + \int_0^T X_t(1-X_t)dW_t?
\end{equation}
Where $W_t$ denotes the standard Brownian motion. From my understanding, if $X^n_{t_{k+1}} = X^n_{t_k} + \delta$ or $X^n_{t_{k+1}} = X^n_{t_k} - \delta$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each then the limit would be the standard Brownian motion itself. But I'm not sure how to do it in the case where we are getting a SDE.

Answer (score 1):

If $\delta^n = \sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}$, then $\left\{\left(X^n_t\right)_{t\geq 0}\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in law, also know as convergence in distribution, to a continuous-time process satisfying
$$ X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t X_s \left(1 - X_s\right)dW_s.$$

We can show this by a classic identification of limit, tightness argument. For the details of this style of argument see  Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*. The idea is that when a sequence of random variables is tight then the sequence admits a convergent subsequence. If we can identify a unique limit point for a subsequence under the assumption that it converges, we may conclude that the sequence converges. The convergence follows from a simple result from analysis: if a sequence in metric space is such that every subsequence admits a convergent subsubsequence and each of these convergent subsubsequences converges to the same point, then the sequence converges to that point.

Let $\mathbb{D}_T := \mathbb{D}_T\left(\left[0,T\right], \mathbb{R}\right)$ be the Skorohod space of right continuous real functions on $\left[0, T\right]$, see section 12 of Billingsley. In what follows, we write $\Delta t^n := \frac{T}{n}$ and $\delta^n := \sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}$.

For the identification of the limit, we have that the $X^n$'s and $X$ are Markov processes and $X$ is characterised by its generator $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^2 \partial_x^2$, with domain $C^2\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$. The fact that $X$ is characterised by its generator can be deduced from either general results on the martingale problem, see for example theorem 4.1 in Ethier and Kurtz's *Markov Processes*, or from the fact that the SDE satisfied by $X$ has Lipschitz coefficients and therefore admits a unique strong solution. We denote by $P_n$ the transition kernel of $X^n$ given by
$$P_nf(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t_1}^n\right)\left| X_0 = x\right.\right], $$
for functions $f$ of a suitable class (we will take that class to be $C^2\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$). We will show that the discrete generators of $X^n$,
$$\mathcal{L}_n = \frac{P - I}{\Delta t^n}$$
where $I$ is the identity operator (i.e. $If = f$ for any function), converges to $\mathcal{L}$. Let $f \in C^2\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$,
\begin{gather*}
P^nf(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t_1}^n\right)\left| X_0^n = x \right.\right] = \frac{1}{2} f\left(x + \delta^n x\left(1-x\right)\right) + \frac{1}{2}f\left(x - \delta^n x\left(1-x\right)\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2} \left[f(x) + f'\left(x\right)\left(\delta^n x(1-x)\right) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)\left(\delta^n x(1-x)\right)^2 + f(x) - f'(x) \left(\delta^nx(1-x)\right) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x) \left(\delta^nx(1-x)\right)^2\right] + O\left(\left(\Delta t^n\right)^{3/2}\right)\\
= f(x) + \Delta t^n\frac{1}{2}f''(x) \left(x(1-x)\right)^2 + O\left(\left(\Delta t^n\right)^{3/2}\right).
\end{gather*}
This entails that for $f\in C^2\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$,
$$ \mathcal{L}_nf(x) = \left(x(1-x)\right)^2\frac{1}{2}f''(x)  + O\left(\left(\Delta t^n\right)^{1/2}\right),$$
and $\mathcal{L}_n f \to \mathcal{L}f$ as $n \to \infty$, which is what we wanted to show.

For tightness, we will use a standard criterion, see section 13 of Billingsley. For $x\in \mathbb{D}_T$ and $A \subset \left[0,T\right]$, define $\omega\left(x, A\right) = \sup_{s,t \in A}\left|x(s) - x(t)\right|$ and for $\eta > 0$,
$$\omega'\left(x, \eta\right) = \inf\left\{\max_{0\leq i \leq r-1}\omega\left(x, \left[t_i, t_{i+1}\right[\right): r \in \mathbb{N}^*, \; 0=t_0 < t_1< \dots < t_r = T, \; t_i - t_{i-1} \geq \eta \; \forall i\right\}.$$
A sequence of random variables $\left(Y_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is tight in $\mathbb{D}_T$ iff

1. The sequence $\left(\sup_{t \in \left[0,T \right]}\left|Y_n(t)\right|\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is tight in $\mathbb{R}$
2. For any $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2 > 0$, there exists $\eta > 0$ such that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\omega'\left(Y_n, \eta\right) \geq \varepsilon_1\right) \leq \varepsilon_2$.

For the first point, as for each $n$ $X_0^n \in \left[0,1\right]$ implies that $X_{t_k^n}^n \in \left[0,1\right]$ for all $k = 1, \dots, n$, the sequence $\left\{\sup_{t \in \left[0, T\right]}\left|X^n_t\right|\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is bounded and therefore tight.

For the second, we will control $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\omega'\left(X^n, \delta^m\right) \geq \varepsilon_1\right)$. We fix a specific interval $\left[t_i^m, t_{i+1}^m\right[$. Let $n > m$ and $j$ such that $t_j^n \in \left[t_i^m, t_{i+1}^m\right[$, then for $k$ such that $t_{j+k}^n \in  \left[t_i^m, t_{i+1}^m\right[$
$$X_{t_{j + k}^n}^n = X_{t_i^n}^n + \sum_{j = 1}^k Y_j \delta^n X_{t_{i - 1 + j}^n}\left(1 - X_{t_{i - 1 + j}^n}\right),$$
where $\left(Y_j\right)$ is an iid sequence such that $\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 = 1\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Y_1 = -1\right) = \frac{1}{2}$. Furthermore, we have
$$ \left|X_{t_{j + k}^n}^n - X_{t_i^n}^n\right| \leq \frac{1}{4}\delta^n\left|\sum_{j = 1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor} Y_j\right|.$$
The $\frac{1}{4}$ is the maximum of $x \to x(1-x)$ over $\left[0,1\right]$.
The bound on right hand side uniformly bounds $\left|X_t^n - X_s^n\right|$ for any $s, t \in \left[t_i^m, t_{i+1}^m\right[$.
By the central limit theorem, for $n$ large enough
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left|\sum_{j = 1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor} Y_j\right| = \frac{\sqrt{T}}{4\sqrt{m}}\left|\sum_{j = 1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor} \frac{Y_j}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{m}}}\right| \approx \frac{\sqrt{T}}{8 \sqrt{m}} \left|G\right|,$$
where $G \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$. Thus with a union bound, we have that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\omega'\left(X^n, \delta^m\right) \geq \varepsilon_1\right) \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{0 \leq i \leq m - 1}\omega\left(X^n, \left[t^m_i, t^m_{i+1}\right[\right) \geq \varepsilon_1 \right) \leq m \mathbb{P}\left(\left|G\right| \geq \frac{8\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{T}}\varepsilon_1\right).$$
We can make the right hand side as small as we want by taking $m$ large enough, which shows the second point. With that we have proved that $X^n$ converges to $X$, the solution of
$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t X_s \left(1- X_s\right)dW_s. $$